# Invalid STRING_SPLIT args in SQL Server

Tags: arrays, sql-server, string, csv, split

I am trying to parse a cell that is data type nvarchar(max) like it is csv in SQL Server 2017. I was hoping to use the `STRING_SPLIT` return a row of data for each value in the array-like string. However, when I run the following code I get an error.

```
select this_column
into #t
from that_table
where coordinate_x = 1
and coordinate_y = 7

select * from STRING_SPLIT(#t.this_column, ',')
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   The multi-part identifier "#t.this_column" could not be bound
>   Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   Argument data type void type is invalid for argument 1 of string_split function

How can I parse this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a table to a inline table function, you need to include it in your `FROM`:

```
SELECT {YourColumns}
FROM #t T
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(T.this_column, ',') SS;
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use a cross apply with your temp table

Here's a working example so you can see how that works:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [TestData] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [TestData]
                      )
VALUES ( N'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');

SELECT [b].[value] FROM @TestData [a]
CROSS APPLY[STRING_SPLIT([a].[TestData], ',') [b];
```

So for your situation, just a small tweak to what you already have, something like:

```
SELECT [b].[value] FROM #t a
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(a.this_column,',') b
```